# C# significant digit issue

Tags: c#

I am experiencing a division significant digit problem, but I am not sure what's the best way of fixing it.

In C#, If I do:

```
Math.Round(36 / 4.8)
```

I get 8 as expected, but if I do:

```
Math.Round(36 / 4.8f)
```

typee
I get 7 instead of 8 like I expected.

Looks like some sort of significant digit issue since 36/4.8 = 7.5 (type of double) but 36/4.8f = 7.4999995 (type of single), but I can't seem to figure out why. Is there a way to keep using float but still ensure the result gets rounded 8 correctly?

One way that I was able to to solve this issue is by rounding twice with first one specifying number of digit to round, then round that number again like:

```
Math.Round(Math.Round(36/4.8f, 5))
```

But I rather not do this kind of gymnastics if I don't have to. Is there a better to solve this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually have some sort of pressing need to use float instead of double? Double is preferred.

Comment: AFAIK this types of errors are bound to happen. For deep dive you can go with [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: If you need exact representations of decimal values with finite numbers of digits, use `decimal`.  If you don't, and want to use floating point values, then this is how floating point values work; they don't represent numbers like this exactly, and you can't rely on rounding to get you an exact value.

Comment: Type `decimal` is souped up to be precise enough for financial calculations, its suffix is `m` and the docs even say to think "money" as the mnemonic to remember that. In *most* scenarios that is overkill, its double the bytes needed for a double. Therefore `double` is truly the correct answer here, take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) to understand what is happening here

Comment: @Narish `double` can't represent this value exactly any more than `float` can.  These two particular values just *happen* to overshoot the exact value instead of undershooting it, and in this one particular case that happens to not result in a different rounded value.  For different values, that wouldn't be the case.  If you care about exactly representing decimal values, you need to use a type that does that, and that's not `double`.  If you don't actually need exact representations, then and only then can you consider floating point types.

Comment: @Narish `decimal` is equally bad compared to `float`/`double` - just one is precise for values that are powers of 10 while two others for powers of 2. Neither can represent values like 1/3 or 1/7... It is quite unclear what OP's need actually is (solving generic problem for just one `/4.8` case is not practical for SO) - hopefully OP will [edit] the post to clarify their overall problem.

Comment: J Liu - please [edit] post to clarify what cases you want a solution for - right now the post shows a single case - indeed that can be solved with replacing the division with an explicit check `(a==36.0 && b=4.8 ?  7.5 : a/b`. Unfortunately, that is not enough to write a good general answer suitable for SO.

Comment: The whole issue of how computers do decimals is rooted in this divide of our calculations assuming base 10 vs computers assuming base 2. So to say its equally bad may be mathematically true but in terms of practicality, decimal is close enough. In any case, my major point is that it is a best practice to *not* use decimal as the hammer for every perceived nail as it is a much larger but potentially wasteful byte allocation. In any scenario, a programmer has to know that floating point numbers should come along with intentional use of rounding methods to adjust them to your business needs